# tinyMCE Paste From Word in IE not working with line breaks

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, wysiwyg, copy-paste

This is tested using IE9.  All other browsers will work except IE and of course our client only uses IE...go figure.  So here's the issue we are having.

If you click the "paste from word" button and the dialog box loads up, if you paste anything that has more than one paragraph it breaks completely and nothing will get pasted in with you click the "insert" button.

However if you paste in something that doesn't have a line break it will work no problem.  So I'm betting on it's something IE isn't liking with line breaks that the editor is trying to give it.

Has anyone ran into this issue and if possible knows how to fix it?  We are running the latest version tinyMCE and this seemed to happen soon after IE9 launched.

Comment: We have tracked it down to be the jquery version of tinyMCE only if we flipped back to the original version with no jquery it will work.  I'll be submitting a bug report but if anybody has anything to comment on please do so.

Comment: i strongly advise anyone to never use the jquery tinymce build (it is slow too)